# Should I use "Be + Infinitive form" in these cases?

Tags: grammar, verbs, infinitives

As the questions says, I would like to know if I can use this structures in these following examples.

> The most sensible thing to do *is to stay indoors*.

> One of the qualities I could have *is to argue* without being obnoxious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an infinitive phrase (to stay indoors) as a noun, linked by "is", the form of "to be", to the noun phrase "the most sensible thing". The second sentence works too, although it would make more sense as "One of the qualities I would like to have is to argue without being obnoxious."